# What is the easiest way to compare two lists?

Tags: c#, linq, list

Using C#, I have a list of objects and a list of ints. For example, I have a list of events, each with an eventId.

I want to compare the events list with the list of ints, and remove any objects, whose ID appears in the list of ints.  So, for example, I have a list of objects like so:

```
Event Id     Event Name
1            Event1
2            Event2
3            Event3
```

and my list of ints contain 1, and 3.  So I would like to remove Event1 and Event3, leaving my only Event2.  What's the best way of doing this?

I also want to do it in reverse.  So I also want to get a list of ints that don't appear in the object list.  So I'd have a list of events that don't appear in the list of ints, and then I'd have a list of ints that don't appear in the list of objects.

As it stands now, I'm using multiple foreach and if statements, and it seems very inefficient, it's a lot of code for something that should be easier.  I know it's probably doable using linq, but I'm still learning and haven't fully grasped linq yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you guessed, you can use LINQ. You have a list of events, you want to get those events where the id exists in a second list.

```
var result = listOfEvents.Where(ev => listOfInts.Contains(ev.Id)).ToList();
```

And the reverse:

```
var result = listOfEvents.Where(ev => !listOfInts.Contains(ev.Id)).ToList();
```

Note this creates a *new list* that contains your result, it doesn't modify the list in place.  I'd suggest the LINQ approach is preferable, but if you really wanted to do this, you can use the [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method on `List<T>` and pass similar predicates:

```
listOfEvents.RemoveAll(ev => listOfInts.Contains(ev.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.

Comment: Depending on the use of result, you might consider not adding the call to the ToList() method in the end.
LINQ uses defered evaluation. Calling ToList() forces evaluation right away.